# Show new progress in UI for each request in Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, progress-bar

I have a task in hand where I have show progress for each request processed by the Spring controller. The progress should be new for each new request. One user can place one request at a time. The web-application is based on Spring MVC and ajax is used for calling the controller.

I want to write all the progress logic on server side only and since multiple users can use the app at one given time, each user should be able to see the progress of the request he/she has made.

How do I start with this task and how could this be done. Some basic examples and pointer explanation would be helpful if not the entire code.

Comment: Do you mean the progress of some background process, which was started by the user or your http requests are taking so much time, that you need to show their progress?

Comment: It's the http request which is taking time(it would take a desired amount of time) and for that, progress is needed.

Comment: You could save the progress of the request in the http session or the database.